# Money Rails - Order Of Amount And Currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

Does the `money-rails` gem require a specific order of `price` and `currency` when initializing an object? For example, take a look at the following:

```
Object.new(currency: 'JPY', price: 25)
=> #<Object id: nil, price_cents: 25, currency: "JPY">
```

If we specify the `price` first, we get an incorrect value (2500) for the price:

```
Object.new(price: 25, currency: 'JPY')
=> #<Object id: nil, price_cents: 2500, currency: "JPY">
```

`Object` contains the following: `monetize :price_cents`.

Comment: In the code above there is no one line where `RubyMoney` gem is involved.  `Object#new` is not overwritten by `RubyMoney` afaik.

Comment: You had to assume that we're using the gem. I editing the question to show that `Object` is monetizing `price_cents`.

Comment: I do not have to assume anything. You are talking about `money-rails` gem, that transparently makes use of `monetize` gem; you’ve never mentioned neither of them in the question. `RubyMoney` itself does not have `monetize` method.

Comment: You're correct. I've updated the question.

Comment: Have you passed [`:with_model_currency`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#instance-currencies) to `monetize` DSL?

Comment: No. It uses the default `currency` attribute.

Comment: If the currency is not a subject toi change from one model instance to another, it makes no sense to pass a currency to constructor.

Comment: It is subject to change.

Comment: Than re-read the documentation I linked in my previous comment _carefully_.

Comment: The side-effect you encountered is likely produced my implicit money convertion to JPY, that apparently has no cents, and since the gem is not aware of that the currency is a subject to change, it performs the rude conversion. On the other hand, when the currency is received as the first argument, no conversion is done, obviously.

Comment: `with_model_currency: :currency` does not change anything. The order of `currency` and `price` needs to be specific in order for it to store the correct value. The issue is that I don't control over the order that is sent over an API, for example.

Comment: Try to set `price_cents` rather that `price` to avoid conversion.

Comment: Ok, I think that'll work. I guess the order is specific for dollar amounts.

Comment: As I have already said, the order is specific for those currencies, having not 2 decimals. For dollars everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the order matters for certain currencies (including JPY because it doesn't have cents). This may not be the best solution but if anyone is stuck, here is what I did.

I added the following to the `self.monetize` method in `money-rails` to override the initialize methods for classes that use it:

```
define_method "initialize" do |opts = {}|
  opts = opts.deep_symbolize_keys
  opts = {currency: opts[:currency]}.merge(opts)
  super(opts)
end
```

This way it will send the currency first.